# How to Integrate Quickblox with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webrtc, quickblox

How to integrate Quickblox with AngularJs?

I already have done Login using it's sample's js and also getting response of incoming call looking at console.

But now I want to integrate Quickblox's listeners like

`onCallListener,onAcceptCallListener,onRejectCallListener` etc. are not working.

Please help me to solved it out, what i have missed? Thanks.

Comment: the same issue I am getting right now. I can not use the listeners of sample's app.js in my controller. also can not use that listeners outside than app.js @coDe murDerer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below code in body of your main index page for quickblox integration.

```
<aside class="msg_board" id="msg_board"></aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link for integrating quickblox into angular js [Here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk)
after integration SDK initialize SDK using user credentials(email or password), then initialize all handler for event handling like.

```
function setupAllListeners() {
  QB.chat.onDisconnectedListener    = onDisconnectedListener;
  QB.chat.onReconnectListener       = onReconnectListener;
  QB.chat.onMessageListener         = onMessage;
  QB.chat.onSystemMessageListener   = onSystemMessageListener;
  QB.chat.onDeliveredStatusListener = onDeliveredStatusListener;
  QB.chat.onReadStatusListener      = onReadStatusListener;
  setupIsTypingHandler();
}
```

then implement function that handle all events like

```
// on message listener
//
function onMessage(userId, msg) {

  // check if it's a mesasges for current dialog
  //
  if (isMessageForCurrentDialog(userId, msg.dialog_id)){
    dialogsMessages.push(msg);

    if (msg.markable === 1) {
      sendReadStatus(userId, msg.id, msg.dialog_id);
    }

    // сheck if it's an attachment
    //
    var messageAttachmentFileId = null;
    if (msg.extension.hasOwnProperty("attachments")) {
      if(msg.extension.attachments.length > 0) {
        messageAttachmentFileId = msg.extension.attachments[0].id;
      }
    }

    showMessage(userId, msg, messageAttachmentFileId);
  }
  // Here we process the regular messages
  //
  updateDialogsList(msg.dialog_id, msg.body);
}
```

It will call whenever message is sended from otherend.